# How to write ItemQuery using ListIdSet?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have requirement to retrive Item information for multiple Ids, I am using ItemQuery for the same using below code,but its gives error as "{"Invalid or missing value of the choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' of type 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemsChoiceType4[]'."}".

Please suggest if anyone is having any idea about how to use ListIdSet for ItemQuery .

```
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType> ids = new List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType>();
        ids.Add(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { Value = "123460", idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.NG });
        ids.Add(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { Value = "789100", idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.NG });
        ids.Add(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.IdType() { Value = "111213", idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.idDomainEnum.NG });



        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemQuery qbdQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemQuery();
        List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item> itemQueryResult = null;
        qbdQuery.Items = ids.ToArray();
        qbdQuery.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType4[] { ItemsChoiceType4.ListIdSet};
        itemQueryResult = qbdQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item>(context).ToList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item>();
```

Regards,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
ItemQuery qbdItemQuery = new ItemQuery();
qbdItemQuery.Items = new object[] { new IdSet() { Id = new IdType[] { new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.NG, Value = "79841" } } } };
qbdItemQuery.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType4[] { ItemsChoiceType4.ListIdSet };
List<Item> ItemQueryResult = qbdItemQuery.ExecuteQuery<Item>(context).ToList<Item>();
```